# How can I ignore an element from a list when looping through with Jinja?

Tags: jinja2, ansible

I have an output as follows:

```
[{ 
   'stderr': 'error: cannot open file',
},
{ 
   'stderr': '',
}]
```

Jinja snipper:

```
{{ php_command_result.results | map(attribute='stderr') | sort | join('\r - ') }}"
```

Returns a trailing `-` at the end because `stderr` is empty. How can I ignore empty values?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Did you try [rejectattr](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#rejectattr)?

```
{{ php_command_result.results | rejectattr('stderr', 'equalto', '') | map(attribute='stderr') | sort | join('\r - ') }}"
```

Comment: THANK YOU! I was banging my head for hours.

Comment: I find it very annoying that things like this are so difficult to find, in or out of the docs. Ansible and Jinja both have a decent amount of documentation, but the chance of actually finding/learning useful things from that documentation is low IMO :(